# Change the Source of an Image with a Storyboard

Tags: image, xaml, animation, storyboard

How can I change the source of an image with a storyboard? I want to create a small animation and for this I want to change the source of an image with a duration of 0.5 seconds that it looks like a small animation. (A littlebit like a Gif-Animation :) ) Is there a way to do this with a storyboard in Xaml or is the only way to change the image source from code behind with a timer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard animations can only work on properties which the engine could animate. The source of an image isn't such a property, at least not out of the box.

What you could do is prepare several images and use the storyboard to set the Source property several times at different key frames using ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard">
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.Source)" 
        Storyboard.TargetName="Image1">

        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <BitmapImage UriSource="Images/1.jpeg" />
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <BitmapImage UriSource="Images/2.jpeg" />
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```